# python social auth separate urls for signup and login django

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have started to use python-social-auth in a django project to authenticate the users from google, linkedin, and potentially other sources. I was able to integrate it to my project, and to create new users with both google and linkedin. I understand the concept of pipeline but something remains unclear to me,
How to differentiate login and signup? It seems to me that python-social-auth has a single pipeline for both login and signup actions.

I am using the url for signup

```
'/login/linkedin/'
```

Now i have one login page url

```
'people/login/'
```

which has two buttons one is google login and another is linked in login. Now when new user comes on login page and he clicks on linkedin login, ideally it should tell him or show him the page that you are not registered through linked.

but python social auth has only one backend for login. So how to separate the login and signup in python social auth.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to think that python-social-auth has a single pipeline for both login and signup.

You have probably noticed that there is a method called `create_user` in the pipeline:

```
# Create a user account if we haven't found one yet.
'social.pipeline.user.create_user'
```

If we take a look at the source code, that `login` flag is set here:

```
if user:
    return {'is_new': False}  # flag that it should log in the user
```

and registration is a little below:

```
return {
    'is_new': True,   # this is a flag that tells the rest of the pipeline that the user should be registered
    'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)  # this is where object is created
}
```

that `strategy.create_user` eventually uses `create_user` method of your **user model**.

Now, you want to show a different page before registration, right?

There is a concept `partial pipeline` in python-social-auth, which allows to cut the process of the pipeline, do something custom and resume the pipeline after that.

To do that, you create a view and decorate it with `@partial` decorator. Something like this:

```
@partial
def show_custom_page(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    # show your page here
```

Have a look at this [example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/app/pipeline.py) of partial pipeline.

Then, add the path to this view to the `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`.

That is it, it should now show your page.

**Update**

Looks like partial pipeline link is broken. You can find another example [here](http://rahmonov.me/posts/introduction-to-python-social-auth/).

Comment: just FYI, link to example is broken.